# How can I use NEST QueryString and escape the special characters?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am using NEST to communicate with Elasticsearch in my applications.

In this case, the user enters in their search term `F5503904902` which returns the correct result. However, if they search for the query `F5503904902-90190` or `F5503904902-90190_55F` the results do not come back.

I assumed this was because of the special characters, so I attempted to escape them - but then no results come back either. Is my query correct, am I doing something wrong? **Also** I am appending a wildcard to the end of the escaped query to match anything open ended.

**Search Method:**

```
public IPagedSearchResult<MyFileObject> Find(ISearchQuery query)
{
    ElasticClient client = ElasticClientManager.GetClient(_indexCluster, ElasticSearchIndexName.MyFileObjects);
    string queryString = EscapeSearchQuery(query.Query) + "*"; 
    var searchResults = client.Search<MyFileObject>(s => s
        .From(query.Skip)
        .Size(query.Take)
        .QueryString(queryString));



    IPagedSearchResult<MyFileObject> pagedSearchResult = new PagedSearchResult<MyFileObject>();
    pagedSearchResult.Results = searchResults.Documents;
    pagedSearchResult.Skip = query.Skip;
    pagedSearchResult.Take = query.Take;
    pagedSearchResult.Total = Convert.ToInt32(searchResults.Total);

    return pagedSearchResult;
}
```

**Escape Method:**

```
private string EscapeSearchQuery(string query)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(query)) return query;

    //&& || not handled here
    char[] special = { '+', '-', '=', '>', '<', '!', '(', ')', '{', '}', '[', ']', '^', '\"', '~', '*', '?', ':', '\\', '/', ' ' };
    char[] qArray = query.ToCharArray();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (var chr in qArray)
    {
        if (special.Contains(chr))
        {
            sb.Append(String.Format("\\{0}", chr));
        }
        else
        {
            sb.Append(chr);
        }
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

I would love any help or pointers why this isn't working or better ways to accomplish this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ElasticSearch dash and underscore are not special characters, but they are characters that cause the terms to be split.  The important thing is the index on the field.  I recommend setting up a multifield.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/multi-fields.html

Here is an example:

```
PUT hilden1

PUT hilden1/type1/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "multifield1": {
      "type": "string",
      "fields": {
        "raw": {
          "type": "string", 
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

POST hilden1/type1
{
  "multifield1": "hello"
}

POST hilden1/type1
{
  "multifield1": "hello_underscore"
}

POST hilden1/type1
{
  "multifield1": "hello-dash"
}
```

Let's try to find the dashed value:

```
GET hilden1/type1/_search
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "multifield1": "hello-dash"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

That returns no results because ES is splitting the field into two parts behind the scenes.  But, because we setup this field as a multi-field we can query for it based on the ".raw" that we set.  This query will get the results you're looking for.

```
GET hilden1/type1/_search
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "multifield1.raw": "hello-dash"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```