# NEST ElasticSearch.NET Escape Special Characters

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have been experimenting with the use of the NEST client for Elastic Search, but seem to have hit a barrier when filtering on a term which contains special/reserved characters such as '/'

Below is a JSON representation of my model..

```
"categories": {
    "count": 1,
    "default": "root/Hello/World/Category",
}
```

When submitting a search for any part of the categories.default field, for example "root" or "Hello" i will receive a match, however when searching for the full string, or any string containing '/' no matches are found.

I understand from some research, that this is because reserved characters are replaced during the indexing/tokenisation process - however I have yet been unable to determine a way around the issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Example search query added below

```
var result = ElasticSearchClient.Search<Schema.Product>(s => s
    .From(0)
    .Size(10)
    .MatchAll()
    .FilterRaw("{ \"term\": { \"categories.default\": \"root/Hello\" } }")
);
```

Comment: It's not completely clear that NEST is the problem. I suspect that your string's analyzer may be splitting on the `/`, thus making it so that your match is different than you expect it to be (I'd expect that you could match against four terms, `root`, `hello`, `world`, and `category`).

Comment: Can you include your mappings & your query in the question ? It'll help finding the problem quickly

Comment: I am almost certain that this is the case, as I am not using any special mappings (aside from the auto mapping in the NEST library). I did take a look at index analyzers, but was not sure which I would need to use in order to force a full match only (ideally I would like to filter by category or url)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to setup a multifield as the dash is causing the terms to be split. I have found an answer to a similar question which answers yours: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28859145/4134821